# Django AJAX call url not found

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, asynchronous, django-views

I want to pass data from an AJAX call to my django view.

**My html:**

```
<a href="javascript:" class="word_known btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-songpk="{{song_pk}}" data-userpk="{{user_pk}}">Yes</a>
```

**My jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var known_words = 0;
  $(".word_known").click(function() {
    known_words++;
    var reference = this;
    var songpk = $(this).data('songpk');
    var userpk = $(this).data('userpk');
    $.ajax({
      url: "/videos/songs/vocab/"+songpk+"/"+userpk+"/",
      data: {known_words: known_words},
      success: function(result) {
    $(reference).removeClass("btn-warning");
    $(reference).addClass("btn-success");
    $(reference).text("Known");
  },
      failure: function(data) {
        alert("There is an error!")
      }
      })

});
})
```

**My view:**

```
def word_known(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        pass
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        request.GET.get('known_words')
        known_words = request.session.get('known_words')
    return known_words
```

**My url for my `videos` app:**

```
   path('songs/vocab/<int:pk_song>/<int:pk_user>/known_words=<int:count>', views.word_known, name='song-known'),
```

The `known_words` variable seems to be working (when I click the count goes up), but I get a 404 error. The following url is displayed: `GET http://dev-lr:8000/videos/songs/vocab/1/3/?known_words=1 404 (Not Found)`.

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem was that I missed a forward slash in my url path, and I also didn't include all the necessary arguments.

So I changed my view like this:

```
def word_known(request, pk_song, pk_user):
    if request.method =='POST':
        pass
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        known_words = request.GET.get('known_words', '')
        # known_words = request.session.get('known_words')
        print('The number of known words is {}'.format(known_words))

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(known_words))
```

And my url like this:

```
path('songs/vocab/known/<int:pk_song>/<int:pk_user>/', views.word_known, name='song-known'),
```

And now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems that your view's path is configured differently than the one you are calling in the frontend. See that you are missing the initial `?` for the query string in the path, and hence the 404. I would suggest that instead of hardcoding the URL by code, you should use the `{% url %}` template tag, like

```
url: "{% url 'song-known' songpk userpk known_words %}"
```

You can do the same in the rest of your Javascript code, think that the Django templating occurs before the page is served, so you can use your template variables in that part without problem, like:

```
var songpk = '{{songpk}}';
```

and then you avoid the need to fetch the value from the HTML element.

Another thing that seems weird to me in the code is the way you are handling things (using a GET request to submit some kind of data), but that is another story for another question :)